Attempted to load class "ModelData" from the global namespace when trying to parse data using PHP SDK
I have a php application, and am using an SDK to call data from an endpoint. The data returned is wrapped in a data object, so it is formatted like this:
{
  "data": {
    "id": "12345",
    "key": "0008",
    "type": 2,
    }
}

When I try to call the API via the SDK, it is unable to parse the above data. I am getting the error:
Attempted to load class "ModelData" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Api\Internal\Model\ModelData"?

The error is being thrown by the autogenerated file in the SDK called ObjectSerializer.php. So it knows the 'data' object being parsed is of type ModelData, and the model for ModelData is present in the SDK. It is an autogenerated file that is created on deployment so it can't be modified. The SDK is being generated from a nest js app using OpenApi.
Any idea how to parse the data without getting the above error?

Did you search for an update? Have tried downgrading one version?

@MarkusZeller Ya, I couldn't find a version that doesn't give the above error.
